# AJAX call based on select value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to get different data to display based on a `select` value. This `select` is in a Bootstrap modal which I am displaying different products by running a loop. I already have all of the data that I need without running an AJAX request, although I think that I may need to run one to display the data now.

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Output the amount of stock from `row['size_sm']` if I select `small` or from `row[size_lg]` if I select `large` and so on.
2. Hide `size` from the select if the size is out of stock. My method does not seem to be working as options are still showing even when they are out of stock.

Here is my code. I'm passing the value from the database via the div classes inside of the link clicked to open the modal that do not show on the page as they are empty but it does not seem to work for the stock sizes.

I don't really understand AJAX, if that is the way to go about this, and I am stuck. What is my best route here? I don't really want to build the whole modal again as I have a carousel inside the body which works fine displaying 
pic1, pic2, pic3 from the database.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".t_shirt_pic_main").on('click', function() {
    //   // get the title of current item and add to modal from the "value" of the item a link that opens modal
    var title = $(this).attr("value");

    // get the image by going inside the a link to the image.. faster than first child   
    var main_pic = $(this).find('.main_img').attr('src');
    var second_pic = $(this).find('.pic2').attr('rel');
    var third_pic = $(this).find('.pic3').attr('rel');
    var price = $(this).find('.price').attr('rel');

    var stock_xl = $(this).find('.stock_xl').attr('rel');
    var stock_lg = $(this).find('.stock_lg').attr('rel');
    var stock_md = $(this).find('.stock_md').attr('rel');
    var stock_sm = $(this).find('.stock_sm').attr('rel');

    // get the title of current item and add to modal from the "value" of the item a link
    $("#modal_title").text(title);

    // change modal pics to the ones from the clicked on item getting values from hidden inputs 
    $("#first_slide").attr('src', main_pic);
    $("#second_slide").attr('src', second_pic);
    $("#third_slide").attr('src', third_pic);

    // add price in the bottom of modal
    $('#modal_price').html('£' + price);

    if (stock_sm == 0) {
      $('#option_small').hide()
    }

    if (stock_sm != 0) {
      $('#option_small').show()
    }

    if (stock_md == 0) {
      $('#option_medium').hide()
    }

    if (stock_md != 0) {
      $('#option_small').show()
    }

    if (stock_lg == 0) {
      $('#option_large').toggle()
    }

    if (stock_lg != 0) {
      $('#option_large').show()
    }

    if (stock_xl == 0) {
      $('#option_extralarge').toggle()
    }

    if (stock_xl != 0) {
      $('#option_extralarge').show()
    }

    $("#t_shirt_and_jumper_modal").modal('show');
  });

});
```

```html
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 products">
    <a class="t_shirt_pic_main" href="javascript:void(0)" value="<?php echo $row['title'] ?>" rel="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
      <!-- hidden values to pass to jquery for the modal -->
      <div class="stock_xl" rel="<?php echo  $row['size_xl'] ?>"></div>
      <div class="stock_lg" rel="<?php echo $row['size_lg'] ?>"></div>
      <div class="stock_md" rel="<?php echo    $row['size_md']; ?>"></div>
      <div class="stock_sm" rel="<?php echo $row['size_sm'] ?> "></div>
      <div class="pic2" rel="<?php echo $row['image_2'] ?>"></div>
      <div class="pic3" rel="<?php echo $row['image_3'] ?>"></div>
      <div class="price" rel="<?php echo $row['price'] ?>"></div>
      <img class="img-fluid main_img" src="<?php echo $row['image_1'] ?> ">
    </a>
    <h5 class="item_title"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></h5>
    <p class="price_para">£<?php echo $row['price'] ?></p>
  </div>
  <?php include "includes/t_shirt_and_jumper_modal.php" ?>
<?php } ?>

<!-- Here is the modal i thought it would be easier to read putting it underneath instead of in the loop -->
<div class="modal-footer">
  <form action="basket.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="size">Size</label>
        <? here i would like to hide the size from the select if the stock is empty ?>
        <select name="size" id="size">
          <option id="option_small" value="sm">small</option>
          <option id="option_medium" value="md">medium <span id="available"></span></s>
          </option>
          <option id="option_large" value="lg">large <span id="available"></span></s>
          </option>
          <option id="option_extralarge" value="xl">x-large <span id="available"></span></s>
          </option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <? HERE IS WHERE I WANT THE INFO $row[size_selected] to display once i choose a size. ?>
      <p> Available: <span id="available"> </span> </p>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
        <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity"> <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Add to basket <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: seems like you arent adding a semicolon: `;` after your `if(){}` statements in ` $('#option_small').show()<--`

Comment: Check your console for `errors` , post that also .

Comment: Instead of putting results in hidden `<div>` tags, I’d instead put the values in a JavaScript array so it’s easier to grab in your jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

sorted now i was able to do it without a ajax call and just by passing the values via div attributes it was still holding the id from the last item clicked on as it was in a loop and i was able to fix it with jquery  and javascript i used on change in the select to display amounts of stock and the .remove to clear the modal of previous item when it was closed here is the code i used incase anybody else has the same problem `    // size 
          $('#size').change(function(){

```
      var selected_size = $(this).children("option:selected").val();

        if(selected_size == "sm"){
           $('#display_stock').html( stock_sm )  
        };

        if(selected_size == "md"){
          $('#display_stock').html( stock_md )  
       };

       if(selected_size == "lg"){
        $('#display_stock').html( stock_lg )  
       };

      if(selected_size == "xl"){
       $('#display_stock').html( stock_xl )  
      };

    });

    // clears modal so that we dont pick up ids from previously clicked on stock 
    //and so select size returns to please choose
    $('#t_shirt_and_jumper_modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
      // location.reload();
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#t_shirt_and_jumper_modal').remove();
      },500)
    });`
```